# sqlite search part of column in array

Tags: sqlite

I have some columns with for example: value1="red,blue,white" value2="green,white" value3="blue, white".also I have an array="red, green". I want to getcolumns that in their value have 'red' or 'green'. in this example result will be (value1 and value2).
I used a loop and every time I checked the values is like array[index] or not. is there better way?

Comment: If you want to get help, you must explain the problem better, by posting definitions of the table and sample data and what kind of array you're talking about, in which programming language?

Comment: Generally in SQL you want to store each element in it's own row of a table instead of trying to store multiple values in a single field.